# How to auto increment NULL value in SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have the following table that has `NULL` values for the **ID** field. I'd like to create a query that'll replace all `NULL` values with auto incrementing numbers based off the max **ID** currently in the table.

```
| ID          | OBJECT  |
|------------ |-------- |
| 5637144579  | Obj 1   |
| NULL        | Obj 2   |
| 5637144584  | Obj 3   |
| NULL        | Obj 4   |
```

So the end result should be

```
| ID          | OBJECT  |
|------------ |-------- |
| 5637144579  | Obj 1   |
| 5637144585  | Obj 2   |
| 5637144584  | Obj 3   |
| 5637144586  | Obj 4   |
```

Notice that the `NULL`s were replaced with autoincrementing numbers based off of the previous max **ID** value after each update.

Right now, I have

```
SELECT
  ...
  ((select MAX(ID) from [dbo].MYTABLE) + 1 ) ID
  ...
```

But that results in `5637144585` for both `NULL` **ID** values.

Comment: Which is it, MySQL or SQL Server? The answer is different.

Comment: @BaconBits, the use of `[dbo]` suggests it's Microsoft SQL Server. That's not legal syntax for identifiers in MySQL. I'll remove the [tag:mysql] tag. Stack Overflow insanely tries to suggest the mysql tag for any question about SQL language.

Comment: @BaconBits, sorry about the confusion. It's SQL Server as Bill suggested.

Comment: What version of SQL Sever? 2012/2014/etc.

Comment: @tarheel SQL Server 2016 (SP1-CU5)

Answer (score 1):

Try this Answer:

```
DECLARE @MYTABLE TABLE(ID BIGINT, OBJECT VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO @MYTABLE VALUES (5637144579,'OBJ 1')
INSERT INTO @MYTABLE VALUES (NULL,'OBJ 2')
INSERT INTO @MYTABLE VALUES (5637144584,'OBJ 3')
INSERT INTO @MYTABLE VALUES (NULL,'OBJ 4')

UPDATE A SET A.ID=B.RN
FROM @MYTABLE A,(
    SELECT *
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY OBJECT)+(SELECT MAX(ID) FROM @MYTABLE)RN
    FROM @MYTABLE
    WHERE ID IS NULL)B
WHERE A.OBJECT=B.OBJECT

SELECT * FROM @MYTABLE
```

**Output:**

```
ID          OBJECT
5637144579  OBJ 1
5637144585  OBJ 2
5637144584  OBJ 3
5637144586  OBJ 4
```

Comment: why are you not using the standard JOIN syntax ?

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve it is using the `sum` over as a running count of the number of null `ID` values and adding it to the previous `max(ID)` value.

**Sample Data:**

```
create table #sample
    (
        ID bigint
        , [object] char(5)
    )

insert into #sample
values (5637144579, 'Obj 1')
, (NULL, 'Obj 2')
, (5637144584, 'Obj 3')
, (NULL,  'Obj 4')
```

**Answer:**

```
declare @max_id bigint = (select max(s.id) as id_bgn from #sample as s)

; with prelim as
    (
        select s.id
        , s.[object]
        , iif(s.id is null, 1, 0) as id_is_null
        from #sample as s       
    )
select isnull(p.id, @max_id + sum(p.id_is_null) over (order by p.[object] asc)) as id
, p.[object]
from prelim as p
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is more simple solution

**Build Table**

```
DECLARE @MYTABLE TABLE(ID BIGINT, OBJECT VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO @MYTABLE VALUES (5637144579,'OBJ 1')
INSERT INTO @MYTABLE VALUES (NULL,'OBJ 2')
INSERT INTO @MYTABLE VALUES (5637144584,'OBJ 3')
INSERT INTO @MYTABLE VALUES (NULL,'OBJ 4')
```

**Answer**

```
DECLARE @N BIGINT

SELECT @N = Max(ID) FROM @MYTABLE

UPDATE @MYTABLE
SET @N = @N+1,
ID = @N
WHERE ID IS NULL

SELECT * from @MYTABLE
```

Answer (score 0):

IF you want to select only you can simply do so:

```
SELECT ID, Obj FROM test
   WHERE ID IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT (SELECT Max(ID) FROM TEST) + ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY OBJ) AS ID, OBJ
    FROM TEST WHERE ID is NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @MYTABLE TABLE(ID BIGINT, OBJECT VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO @MYTABLE VALUES (5637144579,'OBJ 1')
                            ,(NULL,'OBJ 2')
                            ,(5637144584,'OBJ 3')
                            ,(NULL,'OBJ 4');

;With CTE AS(SELECT (SELECT MAX(ID) from @MYTABLE)+ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY ID) AS id,
                    Object 
              FROM @MYTABLE WHERE id IS NULL)

SELECT ISNULL(T1.id,CTE.id) as ID,
        T1.Object
 FROM @MYTABLE T1  FULL JOIN CTE
   ON (CTE.Object=T1.Object)

    --- ------------
    ID         Object
    ---------------------
    5637144579  OBJ 1
    5637144585  OBJ 2
    5637144584  OBJ 3
    5637144586  OBJ 4
```